# Update array_c with values of array_a not found in arrac_b

Tags: postgresql

I have three array columns in a postgres table.

column `array_a` has values like `{"red","blue","green"}`

column `array_b` has values like `{"blue","green"}`

I would like to update column `array_c` to the array from `array_a` with any value found in `array_b` removed

so in this case `array_c` would be `{"red"}`

```
update my_table
set array_c = (
array_remove(array_a, UNNEST(array_b)));
```

works except that if `array_b` is `Null` everything is removed.

I can fix that by separating out the query into

```
WHERE array_b IS NOT NULL
```

and

```
WHERE array_b IS NULL
```

but is there a way to catch the null problem within the original query?